# Wordpress Child theme's css not loading

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-style

i created the child theme like https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Here is my style.css

```
/*
Theme Name: Flatsome Child
Description: This is a child theme for Flatsome Theme
Author: UX Themes
Template: flatsome
Version: 3.0
*/

/*************** ADD CUSTOM CSS HERE.   ***************/

@media only screen and (max-width: 48em) { }
/*************** ADD MOBILE ONLY CSS HERE  ***************/

.absolute-footer.dark {
color: rgb(74, 74, 74) !important;
}
.absolute-footer.dark {
color: rgb(74, 74, 74);
}
h3
{
background-color: #c75050 !important;
}
```

But changes in child theme's style.css not working as expected. I used the following code in my child theme's functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_child_styles', 20 );
function load_my_child_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css', array('twentyfourteen-style'), '1.0.0' );
}
```

But it also not working. Please let me know is how to make style.css to work

Comment: Hi. What do you mean 'Not working as expected'? Is the child theme's style being loaded or not?

Comment: Child theme's styles not loaded

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some problem with your functions.php code. Try using this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/182023/110516