# How to create child theme with Tesseract theme?

Tags: themes

I know this have been answer multiple times... I was looking through this coding.. 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes   & [Versioning @import of parent theme's style.css](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/163301/versioning-import-of-parent-themes-style-css)   & [How to enqueue style before style.css](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96161/how-to-enqueue-style-before-style-css/96163#96163)

This is my development site...http://hoho25974.staging-cloud.partnerconsole.net/

I had change the parent theme when I was developing in my localhost then i came across to creation of child theme. but after reading the above post.. I am quite confused on how to link the child theme and parent theme together.. and i am not sure which codes have to go where... then when i created the Tesseract child theme folder with its style.css and functions.php... i get this message from my theme section in wordpress.

> Broken Themes
>
> The following themes are installed but incomplete. Themes must have a
>   stylesheet and a template.
>
> Name  Description  Tesseract Child    The parent theme is missing. Please
>   install the "tesseract" parent theme.

and i havent touched coding in 8 years.. and i am new to wordpress... if someone could please guide me in the right direction of where to put the coding to link up the child and parent themes together that would be much appreciated! thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the instructions as listed at http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Specifically, in your `wp-content/themes` folder:

- create another directory named `Tesseract-child`
- in `Tesseract-child` create a `style.css` file
- in your `style.css` file include the following header

**style.css contents:**

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Tesseract Child
 Theme URI:    http://example.com/
 Description:  Tesseract Child Child Theme
 Author:       John Doe
 Author URI:   http://example.com
 Template:     Tesseract
 Version:      1.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Text Domain:  tesseract
*/
```

The important part to note here is the `template: Tesseract` attribute which should contain the name of the parent theme directory.

- next in your child theme `functions.php` file include the following snippet

**functions.php contents:**

```
function theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( $parent_style ));
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

...which will enqueue your child theme `style.css` file with the parent `style.css` as a dependency.

- lastly, in your WordPress dashboard goto Appearance -> Themes and activate your child theme - **Tesseract Child**

This should be sufficient enough to get you going.

Comment: thank you @userabuser for your detailed answer.. I am reading the post like you mentioned again.. but i still get the same broken theme message.. this is what i have done in my coding:

'function theme_enqueue_styles() ........
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
 ' 
just after the 'if ( ! function_exists( 'tesseract_setup' ) ) :' in the functions.php .... but the broken theme message is still showing... am i doing something wrong?

Comment: i have found out why i couldnt see the child theme... as in my theme comments.. i was case sensitive to the parent theme name.. now i can see and activate the child theme.. but when i try to activate the child theme.. i see this error message

**Fatal error: Cannot redeclare tesseract_widgets_init() (previously declared in /websites/ho/hoppt.com.au/wp-content/themes/Tesseract-Child/functions.php:132) in /websites/ho/hoppt.com.au/wp-content/themes/Tesseract/functions.php on line 128**

i tried to grey out the commands in line 128 but the error isnt going away.. please help?

Comment: @LynTan There is a fatal error on the front end of your site: `Cannot redeclare tesseract_widgets_init()` **make sure you do not copy** the contents of the parent `functions.php` file into your child theme `functions.php`. Start with a blank/empty `functions.php` file in your child theme, then paste the snippet of code above to enqueue your child and parent theme stylesheets. Then activate the theme (if not already).

Comment: thank you so much for your advice on my child theme! it worked ... it put the code in the wrong file.. it worked after i put the code both in the parent and child theme style sheets! YAY! thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted.

Comment: @userabuser you need to explain that `parent-style` is the parent theme style.css handle, which can be pretty difficult to find. It is usually in the `functions.php` file, but not always, check Avada, for example. Anyway, there is no real advantage over the old school `@import` method.